# Debugging with JShell

Tags: java, debugging, java-9, jshell

I write a Java method in JShell and now I want to debug it. I would like to set breakpoints or at least step through an execution line-by-line. Does JShell have these debugging abilities?

Comment: No, it doesn't. See [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/toc.htm).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to clarify further, from the [JEP: The Java Shell (Read-Eval-Print Loop)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) itself, the ***Non-Goals***
 states :

> Out of scope are graphical interfaces and *debugger support*. The JShell
>   API is intended to allow JShell functionality in IDEs and other tools,
>   but the `jshell` tool is *not intended to be an IDE*.

Answer (score 1):

There is some undocumented `/debug` command (Jshell in Java 11). After `/help /debug` command you can see:

```
jshell> /help /debug
  Display debugging information for the jshell tool implementation.
  0: Debugging off
  r: Tool level debugging on
  g: General debugging on
  f: File manager debugging on
  c: Completion analysis debugging on
  d: Dependency debugging on
  e: Event debugging on
```

Notice, if you write `/help` only there is no information about `/debug` command.

Out of Jshell there is [jdb tool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdb.html) for debug.

Comment: Looks like it is intended for debugging the JShell tool itself, not your own personal code that you're running in JShell.